# "Good day" in modern AmE

Tags: phrase-request, idioms, phrases, idiom-request, sentence-request

The phrase "Good day" used in old-fashioned English, as a greeting or when one was going to say goodbye during the day.

Perhaps it is still in common use in Australian English though.

I am wondering what is used in greeting / saying goodbye today in American English, especially, when you have no idea about the time frame you are in. i.e. let's say you are unaware which phrase suits the time situation better between "good afternoon" or "good evening".

Comment: By "AE", do you mean you're asking about Australian English or American English?

Comment: Good point! I meant American English @gotube. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't heard "good morning" or "good afternoon" used to say goodbye in American English, just to say hello. And I haven't heard "good day" used for either. To say goodbye, I'm used to hearing or saying things like:

- Have a nice day
- Take care
- (See/take to) you later/tomorrow/etc.

For greeting when you don't know the time,

- Hello/Hi
- How are you doing? / How's it going?

Comment: In my area, it seems that *good* has been replaced with *have a nice*.  So *Have a nice day/morning/afternoon/evening* are commonly said at parting.  *Good night* is still often said when parting after sunset.

Comment: How about an unspecific time during the day when you are going to greet rather than say goodbye @EllieK-Don'tsupporther?

Comment: Good day might be used in some formal context but people trying to sound la-dee-dah but it is not commonly used anymore. ""Good day, gentleman", he said as he left the room.